# How to convert an array<date> to array<string> in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I would like to convert the array to an array string so that this `["2016-06-02","2016-06-02"]` becomes `2016-06-02| 2016-06-02`

Answer (score 1):

Use `concat_ws(string delimiter, array<string>)` function to concatenate array:

```
select concat_ws(',',collect_set(date)) from table;
```

If the date field is not string, then convert it to string: `concat_ws(',',collect_set(cast(date as string)))`